# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'operation') when build with Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, solidity, vercel

I'm trying to run this:

```
npm run build
```

on my React project having this problem as a result:

*Generating static pages (8/10)TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'operation')
at HistoryCard (C:\Users\alexs\Documents\LearnWeb3\transparency_NFT\client.next\server\chunks\706.js:104:52)*

I have a React component like:

```
export default function Customer(props) {
const getHistory = async (arrayCards, events, pos, order) => {
        ...

      arrayCards.push(<Card key={order} group={Number(event.args._tokenId)} data={completeData} />);
        ...

  };
}
```

An the error is apparently there in that component Card when I try to use the data props I'm passing to the component. Here is where I try to use the props in the Cards component:

```
export default function Card(props) {
    ...
    return (
    <Item>
      <Title>
        {translateState(props.data.operation)}...
}
```

Any idea why this is happing in Nextjs? I paste also a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: ...and the HistoryCard component?

Comment: @AlexYepes that was just that I called the component HistoryCard. I'll change the image so that it doesn't confuse.